# How achieve Jest test coverage for functions invoked in same file

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, code-coverage, ts-jest

Hi I have a javasctipt file with following code-structure:

`main.js`

```js
function myFun(name) {
  console.log(`Hello ${name}`);
}

myFun(); // Invoking fn for as non-test usage.

export default myFun; // This line is added for testing purpose
```

Implmented a unit test for the above file as below:

`main.test.js`

```
import myFun from "main";

describe("main", () => {
  it("coverage for main", () => {
     console.log = jest.fn();
     myFun("X");
     expect(console.log).toHaveBeenCalledWith("Hello X")
  });
});
```

The test are executing and its passing and I am getting coverage report as this:

```
--------------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File                      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
--------------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
main.js                   |       0 |      100 |       0 |       0 | 1 - 7             
--------------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```

I am not understanding why the statement coverage is zero.

Could someone help me understand how to achieve test coverage in this kind of usecase?